# Android - Listview only works after scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I add an onItemClickListener to a custom listview. But this onItemClickListener works only after I have scrolled the listview.

```
    PostListAdapter adapter = new PostListAdapter(getActivity(), bps);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.board_listview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"List Item Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

The xml of a custom row contains only views, textViews and a imageView. 
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
PostListAdapter:

```
Context context;
BoardPostStruct bps[];

public PostListAdapter(Context context, BoardPostStruct[] bps){
    this.context=context;
    this.bps=bps;
}
    @Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bps.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bps[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    PostHolder holder = null;


    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((FragmentActivity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.club_board_post, parent, false);


        holder = new PostHolder();
        holder.userImage = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.club_board_post_user_image);
        holder.userName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.club_board_post_userName);
        holder.postTime= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.club_board_post_postTime);
        holder.postContent= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.club_board_post_textpost);
        holder.commentCount=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.club_board_post_comment_count);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (PostHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    BoardPostStruct data = bps[position];
    holder.userImage = data.userImage;
    holder.userName.setText(data.userName);

    holder.postContent.setText(data.postContent);
    holder.postTime.setText(data.postTime);
    if(!data.commentCount.isEmpty()){
        holder.commentCount.setText(data.commentCount);
        holder.commentCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        holder.commentCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    return row;
}

static class PostHolder{
    ImageView userImage;
    //TextView userName;
    TextView postTime;
    TextView postContent;
    TextView commentCount;
    TextView userName;
}
```

Comment: How do you populate the listview?

Answer (score 0):

i've seen some problems related to `getLayoutInflater`... so in your **getView** method i suggest you to change your `LayoutInflater` construction:

```
//(...)
if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.club_board_post, parent, false);
//(...)
```

hope to be helpful.

Comment: what do you mean "does not work"? the app crash or do the same as before?

Comment: sorry for the late response. I does the same as before, but I found out, that it works on a real device, only on the emulator it doesn't work. But I've only tried on one device, so I can not say if it works for every device.

Comment: the truly difference here is good programming and scalability. in your constructor you get the context of your activity/fragment and use it to inflate your layout instead of calling the class name directly.